# Largest prime factor of $2^{m} \times r -1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization

**Context:** In his paper, Cameron Stewart  [(click here for the paper)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.1274.pdf)  shows that 
the largest prime factor of $2^n-1$ is at least 
$n \times \exp\Big( \frac{\log n}{104 \log \log n}\Big)$ ,
if $n$ is large enough.

**Question:** Is this result valid for $2^{m} \times r -1$ where we can write-
$2^{m} \times r -1=2^{m} \times 2^{\log_2(r)} -1$.

If not, would you please explain why it is not valid or point out which part of the paper declines it?